# SELECT statements have different number of columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1222

I am making a small php website in which you can follow others and then see their post. 
I have three tables- 
1.Posts, which has post_id and author_id
2.follow, which has following and follower
3.users, which has id, username, and all other stuff. I try the following in sql-

```
SELECT * FROM posts,follow,users WHERE posts.author_id=users.id AND users.id=follow.following AND follow.follower='$id' UNION SELECT * FROM posts,users WHERE posts.author_id=users.id AND users.id='$id'
```

Where $id is the id of the user logged in.

It displays the following error-

```
#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

I have searched for hours but I cannot find the answers to match with my query.
I will really appreciate an answer with a better version of the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you union two queries together, the columns on both must match.

Comment: *I have searched for hours but I cannot find the answers* - are you serious?

Comment: @TimG i know that is a reason but I want to know what query I should put instead of mine

Comment: @juergend i am quite a beginner in sql and the other answers include tags which I don't even know of.

Comment: @SHIVANKKACKER is it possible you're really wanting to do a join?  Google `mysql join syntax`.

Comment: @TimG as I mentioned, I am new to sql and i dont quite understand the join statements, would be better if you can guide me in creating a query! Thanks!

Comment: @SHIVANKKACKER, any number of tutorials are available via a short trip through google land.  that is your best resource at this point.

Comment: @TimG thanks! I will voyage the google land :)

Comment: Perhaps using a JOIN instead of UNION will give you the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a JOIN would serve you better ... something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
JOIN users on posts.author_id=users.id 
JOIN followers on users.id=follow.following 
WHERE follow.follower='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you union two queries together, the columns on both must match.

You select from `posts,follow,users` on the first query and `posts,users` on the second.

this won't work.

[From the mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type

Comment: Thank you for answering but it would be great if you can tell me what i should use rather than my query

Comment: impossible to know without more detail about your database structure and specifically what you're trying to accomplish - more detail than what you put in your question.